# need help to understand onChildClick android

Tags: android

Hello i have succeeded to make an expandable list view in my app from an example and much struggle, but i don't really understand how i succeeded to get the right index the user clicked, i mean, i don't really know what's in childData and how groupData and childData are related to each other. I need some help understanding this guys, i had never seen generics in this way. So here are my questions:

1- How childData and groupData are related to each other, is groupData into childData Map?
2- How can `String selectedWord = childData.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).get(NAME);`
   get the right word and header(or group) in the listView?

Here's the code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.expandable_list_layout);

        DBManager db = new DBManager(getApplicationContext());

        List<String> header = db.selectAllCategories();
        List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        final List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();

        for (String category : header) {
            Map<String, String> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            groupData.add(curGroupMap);
            curGroupMap.put(NAME, category);
            List<String> categoryWords = db.selectWordsFromCategory(category);

            List<Map<String, String>> children = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            for (String word : categoryWords) {
                Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                children.add(curChildMap);

                curChildMap.put(NAME, word);
            }
            childData.add(children);
        }

        //create SimpleExpandableListAdapter object...

        lv.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

//How does the below code works? 
//How can i get the group value from the childData map
//i thought childData had only childs in it?
                String selectedWord = childData.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).get(NAME);

                Log.i("You clicked here:", selectedWord)
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

`groupData` and `childData` are two unrelated data structures. Here's an example of their contents in JSONey notation, to understand what goes where:

```
groupData = [{"label": "Group 1" }, {"label" : "Group 2"}]
childData = [
  [{"label" : "Child 1.1"}, {"label" : "Child 1.2"}],
  [{"label" : "Child 2.1"}, {"label" : "Child 2.2"}, {"label" : "Child 2.3"}]
]
```

If your adapter looks at data structure like this, you'd get expandable listview with two groups, two children in first group, three children in second group.

Indexes in `childData` correspond to group, indexes in its inner lists correspond to child inside group. Elements of the inner lists are maps with values that the adapter will bind to textviews in list items.

Hope this helps!